# Shrink Image to Height of Flex Row Without Stretching Image Width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have an image that's contained in a Flex row. The image height shrinks to match the row's height, but the image width does not shrink. How do I make the image width shrink in proportion to the image height, which is the same as the row height?

```
<div id="app-banner-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
</div>
```

```
#app-banner-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-height: 75px;
}

img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9jhvrbwf/15/

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understood your question, do you want both images to stretch equally within your parent div and fill up the remaining space?

Comment: @Dvalo, the image height resizes to fit the row height, but the image width stays the same. I would like the width to resize as well instead of having the image stretch.